# Apple Watch app won't re-install after being deleted on iOS 8.2, just hangs on launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I can install my Apple Watch app (that is in production) on my watch and it loads just fine the first time. If I uninstall it, and re-install it, it installs fine, but when I tap on the icon it just hangs. It has the loading indicator and the name of the app and it won't ever load.

Here is the error from the device log:

`Jul  6 15:20:23 xxxxx-iPhone companionappd[417] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPApplicationManager.m __56-[SPApplicationManager beginUsingPlugin:withCompletion:]_block_invoke264:392> * * * After 10.0 secs, beginUsing: hasn't called us back for plugin with beginUsingInstanceUUID <__NSConcreteUUID 0x127e18800> 53259124-xxxx-454F-xxxx-FD013Dxxxxxx`

`Jul  6 15:20:23 xxxxx-iPhone companionappd[417] <Notice>: (Warn ) WatchKit: <SPApplicationManager.m __83-[SPApplicationManager getOrBeginActivePlugInForApplication:setupBlock:completion:]_block_invoke_2319:478> Unable to start plugin com.xxxxx.watchkitextension 0x127e887c0 with identifier com.xxxxx.watchkitapp (Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=17 "PKPlugin beginUsing: never called back" UserInfo=0x127d62b90 {NSLocalizedDescription=PKPlugin beginUsing: never called back})`

`Jul  6 15:20:23 xxxxx-iPhone companionappd[417] <Notice>: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __51-[SPCompanionAppServer sendToRemoteInterface:call:]_block_invoke492:860> activePlugInForIdentifier: returned nil for application com.xxxxx.watchkitapp`

I can't figure out what is going on. Is this an SDK/OS issue that is out of my hands? Has anyone seen this?

UPDATE: I just read (and confirmed) on the forums that if you restart both the watch and the phone, the watch app will load without issue. Sounds like an OS bug to me.

UPDATE 2: Got a response from a radar I filed:

[image]

I guess its good to confirm they knew about it and fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This definitely sounds like an OS error, as your log even says `Unable to start plugin com.xxxxx.watchkitextension`. That is nothing you can do anything about. I was going to say that you should probably just restart your simulator inorder for it to work properly again. Another option would have been to just reset your simulator and hardware, however that is only the worst case scenario. As the above person said, you should file a radar [here](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem). Lastly, you could try to install it on a real device and then delete it in order to check if it's an simulator bug or it will also happen on normal devices. There's a good chance it's just the simulator being unable start up the app. Hope that helps,
Julian

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue myself and you shouldn't worry about it. It's a common bug in watchOS that everybody is experiencing from time to time, even normal users with third-party apps.

Since watchOS isn't really out of beta (in my opinion), you should wait for the next release, drink a cup of coffee and hope that it will be fixed soon.

I can definitely promise that you aren't alone with this bug and that you can't do anything against until Apple will fix it. If you can't wait, you can create a bug report [here](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing the same issue on a real watch - restarting the watch and the phone helped me, this issue never came back again at least till the next time I had this issue.

OS versions used:

iPhone: **5s**

iOS: **8.3**

Watch OS: **1.0.1**

Thanks to the below forum thread,

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7845

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue running Xcode 7.0 beta 3 iOS 9.0 beta watchOS 2.0 beta.  The simulator error log showed the following.

> Jul 15 09:48:39 mymachine DTServiceHub[69227]:
>   DTMemlimitAssertionFactory: failed to remove active and inactive
>   memory limits for pid 1 (result = -1)
>
> Jul 15 09:48:42 mymachine companionappd[69155]: (Error) WatchKit: 
>   SPCompanionAppServer.m -[SPCompanionAppServer
>   _launchSockPuppetAppForCompanionAppWithIdentifier:options:completion:]:1176
>   Installation of com.mydomain.myapp.watchkitapp failed

I believe this was caused by naming my WatchKit App "Watchkit App" instead of "myapp WatchKit App" when adding the new target to my existing iOS 9 beta swift application.

To fix this, I backed up my InterfaceController.swift and Interface.storyboard files (the only files in the WatchKit App I had changed).  Deleted the WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extension groups in the project.  And, deleted the WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extensions targets.

I re-added the WatchKit target with the correct name of "myapp WatckKit App".  Overwrote the new files with my backup files.  Now the application and watch application run fine.